# How can I make windows reset the power plan to a chosen one after each restart?

Tags: windows-7, windows, power-management

After I start my pc every morning I don't want to check what power plan I am using and comfortably start my favorite game without worrying about whether I left a power saving power plan on. It could be a bat file that I need to execute on windows startup. I dont know which exe handles power plan changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in powercfg command line tool to do that.

To get identifiers for each plan type powercfg -L

To set up a plan type powercfg -S

ex: powercfg -S 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c

You just need to run -S command in a cmd file placed in the startup folder (which you can find in Start menu) once you know the default plan / GUID you want to use and you're good to go.

Recommended reading: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700230.aspx

Comment: yea I've figured it out myself minutes ago :D thanks. marking as answer asap

Answer (score 0):

Windows likes to reset to the "Balanced (Recommended)" power plan.  You can actually change the "Recommended" plan using the `powercfg` command line utility.  Follow this procedure carefully.

### 1) Launch Elevated Command Prompt

Hit the `Start` button on your keyboard or click/tap your `start` orb.  Type `cmd`.  `cmd.exe` should show up in a list.  Right-click that and select `Run as administrator`.  Depending on your security settings, you will see a UAC message.  Go ahead and accept.  This will open an elevated command prompt.

### 2) List Current Power Plans

In the command prompt, type:

```
powercfg -list
```

This will bring up a list of power plans:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -list

Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)
```

The asterisk indicates the active plan.  The `recommended` plan is the one with GUID `381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e`.

### 3) Export the "Recommended" Plan and the Plan YOU Recommend

At the prompt type:

```
powercfg -export "Balanced.pow" 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

This will export the current "recommended" power plan to a file called `Balanced.pow`.  The extension does not matter.  I use `pow` so I can easily see it is a power plan.  Now we have to export the power plan we want to use in place of Balanced.  In my example, I will swap it with `High performance`.
At the prompt, enter the following:

```
powercfg -export "HighPerformance.pow" 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
```

Of course you would use the GUID of whichever power plan you wish to use.

### 4) Delete The Two Power Plans*

*This is the dangerous part.  We are deleting a system default power plan which can negatively impact Windows and could prevent you from using the GUI to edit power plans.  If you exported the power plans, you should be able to recover.

Before we delete the two power plans, we must first set active a power plan we do not intend on deleting.  Deleting the active power plan is also a bad idea.

Enter the following commands at the prompt:

```
powercfg -setactive a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
powercfg -delete 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
powercfg -delete 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
```

There will be no feedback.

### 5) Import the Power Plans exported in step 3.

The key to importing the two power plans back is to remember to import them to each other's original GUID.  Enter the following:

```
powercfg -import "HighPerformance.pow" 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

This command will provide feedback.  Remember the GUID we just used is Window's "recommended" power plan GUID. Now, enter:

```
powercfg -import "Balanced.pow" 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
```

You will again receive feedback.

Now that the plans have been swapped, we can activate our preferred plan which has also become our recommended plan.

```
powercfg -setactive 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

### 6) List Current Power Plans to see the Fruits of our Labo(u)r

You guessed it:

```
powercfg -list
```

That should yield the following result:

```
Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (High performance) *
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)
```

Check the Power Plan GUI in Control Panel, and you will notice that the High Performance plan is now in bold and listed as "(recommended)".

You can see a video tutorial on this on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQtWqrpOLOI)